# Invalid bundle... contains disallowed file 'frameworks'

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, application-loader

Im trying to publish my app through application loader, but I keep on getting this error. I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777958/validation-error-invalid-bundle-the-bundle-at-contains-disallowed-file-fr) however I still get the same error.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: this worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/q/25777958/1334096

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found out the build I was trying to upload was archived in Xcode beta 6 :/ Upgrading to the GM seed solved my problem. Also make sure `Embedded Content contains swift code` is set to "NO" in your build settings for your extension and set to "YES" in your build settings for your containing app.

Comment: I ran into this issue when submitting an update to our Apple Watch app which contained some Swift in the watch extension. Even though I had `Embedded Content contains swift code` set in the watch extension target build setting, this error was still occurring. The solution was to enable this **in the iPhone app target**, even though that target doesn't currently contain any Swift.

Answer (score 7):

Just to add to this. The `Embedded Content contains swift code` worked for me as well. Additionally, I had an extension and I was linking to frameworks in that extension. I was also **copying** the frameworks to the extension, aka creating a `Frameworks` folder. Because that's what you need to do right? Well, I was definitely wrong. I guess the extension's search path knows to look in the containing app's Framework's folder via the Extension Target's **Runpath Search Paths** setting in **Build Settings**

```
@executable_path/../../Frameworks
```

So what was unclear to me, and is now clear is that you don't copy the Frameworks (Copy Build Phase) into the extension. It uses them from the containing application. Which is also why, if you want to use your Frameworks in your extension you need to be sure that the **Build Settings** > **Require Only App-Extension-Safe API** is set to **Yes**

Comment: This makes sense. Also I think it is the only correct solution, since the ```Frameworks/``` folder is on the root folder only. So all the appex are looking at this folder, and the appex root folder does not need to have another ```Frameworks``` nested folder.

Answer (score 4):

I face this issue in Xcode - 11. In my project I have custom framework which was 
add as **Embed & sign**, and it has to be **Do not embed**. See the picture below.[image]

Answer (score 2):

For me, none of the above solutions worked, but in the end [this GH issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3905) gave a hint.

If you're using CocoaPods, you might consider **deleting the *Embed frameworks build phase*** on the problematic target (the extension), this fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This one worked for me. Seems sketchy, but it did resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

For the app, I had to set:

```
Embedded Content Contains Swift Code: YES
```

and for the extension:

```
Embedded Content Contains Swift Code: NO
```

Comment: Does this apply for a Swift-only project with Swift-only frameworks? I don't think so...