# Validation Error: The bundle contains disallowed nested bundles

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect

As a followup to [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156816/validation-error-the-bundle-contains-disallowed-file-frameworks), I'm continuing to have issues submitting my iOS 8 app (which includes a Sharing Extension and a framework target). On a submission attempt I receive the above error message. Others with my issue (as pointed out in the afore-linked question) have the same issue, but resolved it in ways that aren't relevant to my case.

The error message implicates my Sharing Extension target, which links to a framework that I wrote, which is shared between the Extension and the app. I'm pretty sure Apple was clear that I'm allowed to use frameworks in Extension targets (in fact, it's preferred!). So what other causes might there be for this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, the answer seems simple enough: in the Extension target I was embedding the framework (Build Phases > Embed Framework). Once I removed that setting, everything works fine.

Sigh.

Comment: I'm having this same issue and removing the build phase enables me to submit the app. Unfortunately, neither the app's Today or extension or the watch app extension is able to run without the framework embedded since it needs that code to run. What am I missing?

Comment: @GnarlyDog: Make sure the framework is listed in the "Target Dependencies" and "Linked Libraries" sections within the "Build Phases" tab of your target. Maybe you were missing one of those two?

Answer (score 3):

I had to remove 
(Build Phases > Embed Pods Frameworks)
From the today excitation.

Was able to upload to appstore but this bring other problem the today excitation is not working

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking

Answer (score 0):

For me, Aaron's answer was only half the answer.
After removing my framework from my extension's Embedded Binaries, I had to add it to my extension's Linked Frameworks and Libraries.
(Both can be found in the extension's General tab.)