# Invalid Bundle, The bundle contains disallowed nested bundles, contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'

Tags: ios, cocoapods, watchkit

I added a shared framework to share code between app and watch extension. Later I removed the shared framework since it cause lots of problems. I can build
and run my app on iphone and watch. However when I submit to app store, I see these two errors:

`ERROR ITMS-90205: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'xxx WatchKit Extension.appex' contains disallowed nested bundles."`

`ERROR ITMS-90206: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'xxx WatchKit Extension.appex' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'."`

I have tried all the solutions mentioned on stackoverflow([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777958/validation-error-invalid-bundle-the-bundle-at-contains-disallowed-file-fr?lq=1) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160624/validation-error-the-bundle-contains-disallowed-nested-bundles?lq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160624/validation-error-the-bundle-contains-disallowed-nested-bundles?rq=1)) None of them works for me.  How do I fix the error?  Errors message from apple really doesn't give a clue what I should to.

Comment: You'd better provide details of the `target` and `Emeddded Binaries` of each target.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validation Error: Invalid Bundle. The bundle at ... contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777958/validation-error-invalid-bundle-the-bundle-at-contains-disallowed-file-fr)

Comment: See my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608264/error-itms-90451-cfbundleidentifier-collision-error/40396491#40396491

Comment: Vijay's answer also solved this for me.

Answer (score 17):

I still do not fully understand what causes the issue, but I've stumbled upon an answer that has finally solved the issue for me.

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4203

Specifically, the post by mikehouse on Oct 12, 2015 was the solution to the the problem.

Add the following run script to ALL you embedded extension targets. In my case I had to add the run script as a build phase to my Today extension and my Apple Watch App extension.

```
cd "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/"
if [[ -d "Frameworks" ]]; then 
    rm -fr Frameworks
fi
```

Comment: I don't think this is the solution because the scrip will remove the folder named as frameworks and all its content and if the app is dependent on any framework that is removed your app will crash on runtime. As per my understanding you need to contact to developers of that framework. They can remove or rename the folder and rebuild the framework.

Comment: The key point is to have the run script in the end of the build phase.

Comment: Excellent. Resolves the issue when you have a fw dependency graph as opposed to a tree. Saved my day.

Answer (score 6):

The "ITMS-90206" error was resolved in this post: [Validation Error: Invalid Bundle. The bundle at ... contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777958/validation-error-invalid-bundle-the-bundle-at-contains-disallowed-file-fr)

The setting needs to be changed from Yes to No within the Build options of your WatchKit Extension:

```
Embedded Content Contains Swift Code: No
```

Comment: This no longer works by itself in XCode 8.  You need to also set "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries: NO"

Answer (score 6):

The above didn't work for me.

`Embedded Content Contains Swift Code: NO`

Didn't really do anything for me.

I experienced this issue using a dynamic framework.
My dynamic framework contained other dynamic frameworks which made it OK
to have:

`Embedded Content Contains Swift Code: YES`

And instead having the other dynamic frameworks set it to No instead.
But instead of that I had to set

`Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries: NO`

under Build Phases.

Having this one set to YES generated the `frameworks` folder causing upload to ITC fail.

Comment: This worked to pass the upload process (I was getting errors before finishing the upload) bu then got an email from Apple:

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "InstaStickers: Turn Instagram photos into stickers". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

Invalid Bundle - One or more dynamic libraries that are referenced by your app are not present in the dylib search path.

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Regards,

The App Store team

Answer (score 5):

In the main target add:

```
cd "${CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH}"
find ./PlugIns -type d -name Frameworks | xargs rm -rf
```

The problem is that adding SPM packages on multiple targets of the same project will duplicate the dependencies. The frameworks on this extension are probably on the main target so this should be enough. Otherwise use the full script below on the main target, which will deduplicate the frameworks if needed by moving them to the app.

---

Do NOT add this to your extension target. It tries to remove the duplicated framework but it has no effect because it runs before the framework is copied to the extension:

```
# this has no effect if you add it to your extension target
cd "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/"
if [[ -d "Frameworks" ]]; then 
    rm -fr Frameworks
fi
```

---

I ran into this problem in a project that uses Rx as a SPM package in the main target, frameworks, and extensions. If you have the same or similar problem (e.g. [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/swift-package-manager)), you can fix it with the following script in the main target:

```
if ! [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release" ] ; then

    echo "early exit"
    exit 0
fi

cd "${CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH}/Frameworks/"

# copy frameworks to TeamworkProjects.app/Frameworks
for framework in *; do
    if [ -d "$framework" ]; then
        if [ -d "${framework}/Frameworks" ]; then
            echo "Moving embedded frameworks from ${framework} to ${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/Frameworks"
            cp -R "${framework}/Frameworks/" .
            rm -rf "${framework}/Frameworks"
        fi
    fi
done

# remove leftover nested frameworks
for framework in *; do
    if [ -d "$framework" ]; then
        if [ -d "${framework}/Frameworks" ]; then
            echo "Removing embedded frameworks from ${framework} to ${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/Frameworks"
            rm -rf "${framework}/Frameworks"
        fi
    fi
done

# Remove Frameworks from PlugIns
cd "${CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH}"
find ./PlugIns -type d -name Frameworks | xargs rm -rf

# codesign for Debugging on device
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug" ] & [ "${SDKROOT}" != *Simulator* ] ; then

    echo "Code signing frameworks..."
    find "${CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH}/Frameworks" -maxdepth 1 -name '*.framework' -print0 | while read -d $'\0' framework
    do
        # only sign frameworks without a signature
        if ! codesign -v "${framework}"; then
            codesign --force --sign "${EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY}" --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements --timestamp=none "${framework}"
            echo "Added missing signature to '${framework}'"
        fi
    done
fi
```

Most of this script came from user pewe at forums.swift.org: [Swift packages in multiple targets results in duplication of library code](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-packages-in-multiple-targets-results-in-this-will-result-in-duplication-of-library-code-errors/34892/57).

Comment: Can you confirm this works when archiving build?

Answer (score 4):

I add a swift package, which is dynamic library, into sub-projects, and into my main project. When uploading to TestFlight, I encounter this issues too.

As the picture, I change `Embed & Sign` to `Do Not Embed` for the sub-project, and then this issue is resolved.

It keeps `Embed & Sign` for my main project. But in sub-projects, I change them to `Do Not Embed`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had a framework that builded with the following build settings:

`Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries: YES`

`Allow Non-Modular includes in Framework Modules: YES`

So I changed both to `NO` and build framework again.

`Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries: NO`

`Allow Non-Modular includes in Framework Modules: NO`

I added new build of framework to my project so It uploaded to iTunes Connect successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I had a today extension which uses a custom framework I implemented it.

I tried all the solutions but nothing worked for me.

I needed the custom framework only in the today extension, so I linked and embedded this framework in the today extension only.

What the error is saying is:

> that the bundle contains disallowed frameworks

Today extension should not embed any framework, shall only link to it.

So I removed the framework from the today extension and added it to the parent app.

**Note that:**

the parent app should use this framework since it's added to it, an import shall do the job.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone runs into this issue even 8 years or more after this post was posted, here's what worked for me after browsing through various threads:

I had a project with 5 frameworks attached to the project.

[image]

My main target (in this case - `meteo-lt` had all the frameworks embeded and ready for signing. Seems like okay here.

[image]

But the issue was that all the other frameworks were embedding each other too.

For example:

- `MeteoLtUI` was embedding (with or without signing - same issue) `MeteoLtDomain` and `MeteoLtUtilities`.
- `MeteoLtNetwork` was implementing `MeteoLtDomain` and `MeteoLtUtilites`.
- `MeteoLtUtilities` was implementing `MeteoLtDomain`.
- And so on..

All I had to do was to leave Embed & Sign for all frameworks on main target `meteo-lt` and set to `Do not embed` inside all other frameworks, so they wouldn't embed each other and create nested embedding.

In other words:

You can't nest B inside of A.

```
- .app
  - Frameworks
    - A.framework
      - Frameworks
        - B.framework
```

Instead, you need to do it like this:

```
- .app
  - Frameworks
    - A.framework
    - B.framework
```

---

P.S. In case this does not help, and you were planning and are heading to set all frameworks on main target to `Do not embed`, make sure to read these articles before:

https://holyswift.app/frameworks-embed-or-not-embed-thats-the-question/

https://pratheeshbennet.medium.com/static-library-vs-dynamic-library-in-ios-55478ed53a03

Answer (score 1):

Just keep in mind that should not embed & sign the nested framework
[image]
Change Embed & Sign to Do not Embed will solve issue,
I have solved it, thank for AechoLiu answer