# Validation Error: Invalid Bundle. The bundle at … contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'

Tags: ios, ios8, app-store-connect, ios-app-extension

I'm getting these 2 errors when I try to submit my app with a today extension on Xcode 6.1 GM. I've tried [both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777958/validation-error-invalid-bundle-the-bundle-at-contains-disallowed-file-fr) of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777958/validation-error-invalid-bundle-the-bundle-at-contains-disallowed-file-fr) solutions but neither of them work:

```
Validation Error: Invalid Bundle. The bundle at … contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'
Validation Error: Invalid Bundle. The bundle at … contains disallowed nested bundles
```

Both the app and the today extension are written in Swift. I've tried cleaning the project and deleting Xcode derived data but I'm still getting the same 2 errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Of course I found the answer 30 minutes after posting. My problem was I accidentally added the AlamoFire framework to the "Copy Files" section in Build Phases of my extension target. Removing this fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

It helped me:

```
Embedded Content Contains Swift Code: YES
```

and for the extension:

```
Embedded Content Contains Swift Code: NO
```