# Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods

I am facing getting `error` while trying to export archive.

I am using `xcode 7.2'`.

I have tried with solution which are provided [Here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4472) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145023/found-an-uxexpected-mach-o-header-code-0x72613c21-when-trying-to-export-an-ar)

Comment: Could you please add error print-screen, it is not clear what error you are getting.

Comment: Im have  the same issue. did u manage to solve it ?