# AppStore submission does not work with RealmSwift 0.96.0 / Cocoapods 0.39.0

Tags: swift, cocoapods, realm

Using RealmSwift-0.96.0 and Cocoapods-0.39.0 together with Xcode-7.0.1 and iOS-9.0.2:

Trying to submitt to the App-Store, the following error message shows-up during upload:

[image]

Also, having done the pod install, the following message showed up (see image below).

[image]

Can somebody tell me

1) if the messages during pod-install are related to the app-store upload-failure ?

2) what the counter-measure needs to be in order to upload correctly to the app-store ??

Comment: I think the errors are related with the appstore submission errors. Why not follow the suggestion written the console?

Answer (score 0):

The first App-Store upload error (i.e. ERROR ITMS-90205) can be solved by doing what is written in the image1 below (or what was mentioned at the [very bottom of this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777958/validation-error-invalid-bundle-the-bundle-at-contains-disallowed-file-fr/33092433#33092433) from [Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233393/roman)).

The second App.Store upload error (i.e. ERROR ITM-90206) can be solved by doing what is written in the image2 below (or what was mentioned by [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/693563/mike) as an answer [to this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777958/validation-error-invalid-bundle-the-bundle-at-contains-disallowed-file-fr))

image1:
[image]

image2:
[image]