# iOS widget extension works from xcode but not when archived

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions

If i run the extension or app from xcode, they both work fine, but if i archive, create an IPA file and install it via itunes, then the widget is always "Unable to load" (but the app itself still works fine).

I noticed that if i turn "always embed swift standard libraries" on for the widget target, then the widget installed with the IPA *does* work fine. BUT doing this means you can't submit it to the app store ("The bundle at … contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'")

Any ideas on how to find the problem? I can't see how the widget is crashing because it doesn't crash in xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i solved this thanks to step 3 on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29821624/160149

I had to add "@executable_path/../../Frameworks" to Runpath searchpaths in the extension target