# Publishing Failed, Code signing failed, bundle contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, app-store, provisioning-profile, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to submit an app to the app store and am having some issues with Visual Studio/Xamarin's sign and distribute process.  This process has worked for me in the past.  The main difference is that i've added today extensions to my application.  My provisioning profiles seem to be fine.  They are valid and it allows me to select them.

Everything seems fine up until this point in the process.  I select my main app and select it's corresponding provisioning profile.  Then select my today extension app and select it's corresponding provisioning profile.  So both have the green check boxes.  Then I hit Next, and then I hit Publish and select a filename/location.  And it hits me with the red banner screen saying "Publishing Failed" and "Code signing failed".

Also note, I can see the text "signing native libraries" flash right before the red error message pops up.

Any ideas on what might be the issue?

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac Community, 7.0.1 (build 24)

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Edit:**   I opened up my the .xcarchive file that Visual Studio (Xamarin) created.  It opened in Xcode.  I clicked on my thing and then clicked "validate".  It gave me an error.  See screenshot below.

```
iTunes Store operation failed.
Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'MYAPPNAME.app/PlugIns/Widgets.appex' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'.
```

Widgets is the name of my Today Extension.  So clearly there's something it doesn't like about my today extension project.

[image]

If, instead of hitting validate, I select "Upload to App Store" I receive a similar error

```
ERROR ITMS-90206: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'Stringify.app/PlugIns/Widgets.appex' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'."
```

ERROR ITMS-90206: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'Stringify.app/PlugIns/Widgets.appex' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'."

[image]

**Edit:**  Seems like I need to [figure out how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777958/validation-error-invalid-bundle-the-bundle-at-contains-disallowed-file-fr) in Visual Studio/Xamarin.  Since I'm not using Swift I can't just use the accepted answer.  At a glance, I don't see any Framework folder or files.

**Edit:**  I was able to get it working by tweaking build settings one at a time until it worked.  This has the behavior of a bug because the settings I tweaked don't seem like they should have made a difference.  I removed "Perform all 32-bit float operations as 64-bit float" and "Strip native debugging symbols" and then it magically worked.  I have no idea if one of those two or both were causing the problem or it was a complete fluke...

```
Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac
Version 7.0.1 (build 24)
Installation UUID: 0317c808-9e99-457e-bb34-8fe00111cae8
Runtime:
    Mono 5.0.1.1 (2017-02/5077205) (64-bit)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

    Package version: 500010001

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 10.10.0.36 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: d2270eec
Branch: d15-2
Build date: 2017-05-22 16:30:53-0400

Operating System
Mac OS X 10.12.5
Darwin 16.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.6.0
    Fri Apr 14 16:21:16 PDT 2017
    root:xnu-3789.60.24~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: U can check your code-signing of the frameworks. We faced the same issue when were resigning the existing IPA again. Then have to resign the frameworks also with $/usr/lib/codesign -f -s TEAMID --entitlements <entitlement.plust> <AppName> command with the provisioning profile

Comment: and this before that. if [ -d "${APP_PATH_MAIN_TARGET}"/Frameworks ];
  then
   echo "CODE SIGN - started for Frameworks of IPA ...." | tee -a ${_logfile} 

      for SWIFT_LIB in $(ls -1 "${APP_PATH_MAIN_TARGET}"/Frameworks); do
          codesign --force --sign "${ACCOUNT_CERTIFICATE_NAME}" --verbose "${APP_PATH_MAIN_TARGET}"/Frameworks/${SWIFT_LIB}
      done
      echo "CODE SIGN - completed for Frameworks of IPA ...." | tee -a ${_logfile}
  fi