# Error while Publishing the App to the Appstore

Tags: ios, appcelerator

I have Appcelerator project in which I have included Notification Service Extention to read the Rich notification with the image. The code for the Extension is written in the swift. The problem is that when I try to publish the build to App Store I get below error.

```
Invalid Bundle. The bundle at '.app/PlugIns/testapp.appex' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'.
```

Below are the solution which I tried and corresponding results.

- For the Extension app: `Embedded Content Contains Swift Code: YES`. For the extension: `Embedded Content Contains Swift Code: NO`.

**Reference:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/25789145
**Result:** Same Error

- Added the Run Script code in Native Extension Project for Target Extension
  `cd "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/"
  if [[ -d "Frameworks" ]]; then 
  rm -fr Frameworks
  fi`

**Reference:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/33092433
**Result:** Unable to Build the App in Appcelerator Studio. Execution stops after
`[INFO] :   Initializing the build directory
[INFO] :   JavaScript files need to be encrypted
[INFO] :   Creating Xcode project`

Setup details:
Ti SDK : 7.1.1.GA
Ti CLI : 5.0.14
Node.js Version : 8.9.1
npm Version : 5.5.1
OS : Mac OS X

Kindly let me know if anything I am missing. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think Swift frameworks are not yet supported in Titanium. How did you test those frameworks while developing the app?

Comment: I am able to receive the notification on iPhone using the same setup during the Development. Not a bit of code is changed. And the swift code is written  in Xcode for the Native Extension Project. This error only appears while Publishing the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by replacing Swift Notification Extension Project with Objective-C Notification Extension Project. Actually this is weird because Swift Notification Extension Project works perfectly during Development. It causes problem only while publishing your App to the Store. This will help if someone is going through the same issue.