# Xcode 9.3 Swift Nested Custom Frameworks Unit testing and iTunesConnect uploading

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

I am getting tired of messing with build settings after a couple of days now...

I have an app, let's call it `MyiPhoneApp` that uses around 10 private/custom Frameworks (Cocoa Touch Dynamic Framework). `MyiPhoneApp` also uses Cocoapods for some dependencies (irrelevant?). My private Frameworks are themselves using themselves (being dependent on each other).

So my setup is (simplyfied here for readability):

## FRAMEWORKS (Private/Custom Cocoa Touch Dynamic):

### `Models`

**Targets:** `ViewModels`, `ViewModelsTests`
**Dependent on Private Frameworks**: NONE

### `ViewModels`

**Targets**: `ViewModels`, `ViewModelsTests`
**Dependent on Private Frameworks**: `Models`

### `Views`

**Targets**: `Views`, `Views`
**Dependent on Private Frameworks**: `Models`, `ViewModels`

## APPS

### `MyiPhoneApp`:

**Targets**: `MyiPhoneApp`, `MyiPhoneAppTests`, `MyiPhoneAppUITests`
**`MyiPhoneApp` dependent on Private Frameworks**: `Models`, `ViewModels`, `Views`

## Catch 22 running Unit Tests & upload to iTunesConnect

With `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES = YES` for **ALL** targets I can run all unit tests in each private framework. **But** then I get rejection error from iTunes Connect:

> [04:06:20]: [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90206: "Invalid
>   Bundle. The bundle at 'MyiPhoneApp.app/Frameworks/Models.framework'
>   contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'." [04:06:20]: [Transporter Error
>   Output]: ERROR ITMS-90206: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at
>   'MyiPhoneApp.app/Frameworks/ViewModels.framework' contains disallowed
>   file 'Frameworks'." [04:06:20]: [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR
>   ITMS-90206: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at
>   'MyiPhoneApp.app/Frameworks/Views.framework' contains disallowed file
>   'Frameworks'."

This seems similar to: 
(SO Q958)[[Validation Error: Invalid Bundle. The bundle at ... contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25777958/1311272])

[The answer with over 240 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25789145/1311272) from Q958, suggets:
Setting `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES = NO` for Frameworks and Tests Targets (and Frameworks' Test Target..?) and `YES` for Apps. This is also suggested in [this Github comment](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6292#issuecomment-271002382)

When trying that (`ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES = NO` for frameworks and their test target) I cannot run my tests.

When I try to run `ModelTests` (Remember Framwork `Models` is not dependent on any other framework) the test fails/dies with:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /Users/sajjon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Models-ahgxztzgogwcfheblqbzabdqxhtm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Models.framework/Models
>   Reason: image not found

## What is the proper setup?

I have tried Xcode 9.3 and Xcode 9.4. My Frameworks and my App uses this xcconfig files:

### My System

Macbook Pro 15" late 2016
macOS High Sierra v 10.13.5 (17F77)

#### Cocoapods 1.5.3 (bundler)

Bundler version 1.16.1
`bundle exec pod --version => 1.5.3`

### My Podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '11.2'
inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

workspace 'MyWorkspace.xcworkspace'

### PODS (sorted by name) ###

def nimble
  pod 'Nimble',  '~> 7.1'
end

def rxswift           
  pod 'RxSwift', '~> 4.1'
end

def viewcomposer      
  pod 'ViewComposer', :git => 'https://github.com/Sajjon/ViewComposer.git'
end

def quick
  pod 'Quick',  '~> 1.3'
end

# Rest of pods removed for this StackOverFlow question for readability #

# Global Pod used by ___ALL___ targets
swiftlint

#@@ Apps (sorted by name) @@#

target 'MyiPhoneApp' do
  project 'Apps/MyiPhoneApp/MyiPhoneApp'


  # lots of pods removed for this SO question for readability
  rxswift
  tinyconstraints
  viewcomposer

  abstract_target 'Tests' do
    nimble
    quick

    target "MyiPhoneAppTests"
    target "MyiPhoneAppUITests"
  end
end


### PRIVATE FRAMEWORKS ###

abstract_target 'Framework-Models' do
  project 'Common/Models/Models'

  target 'Models' do
    # lots of pods removed for this SO question for readability
    rxswift
    swiftybeaver
  end

  target 'ModelsTests' do
    nimble
    quick
  end
end

abstract_target 'Framework-ViewModels' do
  project 'Common/ViewModels/ViewModels'

  target 'ViewModels' do
    # lots of pods removed for this SO question for readability
    rxswift
    viewcomposer
  end

  target 'ViewModelsTests' do
    nimble
    quick
  end
end

abstract_target 'Framework-Views' do
  project 'Common/Views/Views'

  target 'Views' do
    # lots of pods removed for this SO question for readability
    rxswift
    tinyconstraints
    viewcomposer
  end

  target 'ViewsTests' do
    nimble
    quick
  end
end
```

### My xcconfig files setup

So as you can see in the Podfile above, my private Framework uses pods. But I want to use xcconfig files to share build settings between my frameworks (I only wrote three `ViewModels`, `Views`, `Models`, but in fact I have around 10.).

So I have investigated which xcconfig files that Xcode creates by default for Apps, for Cocoa Touch Dynamic Frameworks and how the settings for these differ between Test target and non Test target and between Debug and Release.

From that I have created these xcconfig files

#### `base_shared.xcconfig`

**includes configs:** NONE
**Description**: Used by ALL targets (App (Main, Test, UITest), Frameworks (Main, Test)).

#### `base_debug.xcconfig`

**includes configs:** NONE
**Description**: Used by ALL debug targets (App (Main, Test, UITest), Frameworks (Main, Test)).

#### `base_release.xcconfig`

**includes configs:** NONE
**Description**: Used by ALL release targets (App (Main, Test, UITest), Frameworks (Main, Test)).

#### `base_apps.xcconfig`

**includes configs:** `base_shared`
**Description**: Used by apps targets (Main, Test, UITest)

#### `base_framework.xcconfig`

**includes configs:** `base_shared`
**Description**: Used by Frameworks (Main, Test).

#### `base_tests.xcconfig`

**includes configs:** `base_shared`
**Description**: Used by all Test Targets (App, Framework).

#### `base_uitests.xcconfig`

**includes configs:** `base_shared`
**Description**: Used by all UITest Targets (App).

Then for each and app framework I include the correct combination of xcconfigs in a `Common` xcconfig. So e.g. for the Framework `Models` I create 6 config files: `Models-Common.xcconfig`, `Models-Debug.xcconfig`, `Models-Release.xcconfig`, "ModelsTests-Common.xcconfig", `ModelsTests-Debug.xcconfig`, `ModelsTests-Release.xcconfig`.

While that results in many xcconfig files, 6 for each framework, they are all tiny. And I can shared ALL build settings between all my 10+ Frameworks. It is a trade off.

### The contents of my xcconfig files

`base_shared.xcconfig`:

```
// BuildSettings shared between both DEBUG and RELEASE and also identical for both FRAMEWORKS (Cocoa Touch Framework) and APPS (iOS)

// Vanilla Xcode 9.3 settings
ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS = NO
CLANG_ANALYZER_NONNULL = YES
CLANG_ANALYZER_NUMBER_OBJECT_CONVERSION = YES_AGGRESSIVE
CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = gnu++14
CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY = libc++
CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES = YES
CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC = YES
CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_WEAK = YES
CLANG_WARN_BLOCK_CAPTURE_AUTORELEASING = YES
CLANG_WARN_BOOL_CONVERSION = YES
CLANG_WARN_COMMA = YES
CLANG_WARN_CONSTANT_CONVERSION = YES
CLANG_WARN_DEPRECATED_OBJC_IMPLEMENTATIONS = YES
CLANG_WARN_DIRECT_OBJC_ISA_USAGE = YES_ERROR
CLANG_WARN_DOCUMENTATION_COMMENTS = YES
CLANG_WARN_EMPTY_BODY = YES
CLANG_WARN_ENUM_CONVERSION = YES
CLANG_WARN_INFINITE_RECURSION = YES
CLANG_WARN_INT_CONVERSION = YES
CLANG_WARN_NON_LITERAL_NULL_CONVERSION = YES
CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF = YES
CLANG_WARN_OBJC_LITERAL_CONVERSION = YES
CLANG_WARN_OBJC_ROOT_CLASS = YES_ERROR
CLANG_WARN_RANGE_LOOP_ANALYSIS = YES
CLANG_WARN_STRICT_PROTOTYPES = YES
CLANG_WARN_SUSPICIOUS_MOVE = YES
CLANG_WARN_UNGUARDED_AVAILABILITY = YES_AGGRESSIVE
CLANG_WARN_UNREACHABLE_CODE = YES
CLANG_WARN__DUPLICATE_METHOD_MATCH = YES
COPY_PHASE_STRIP = NO
ENABLE_STRICT_OBJC_MSGSEND = YES
GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = gnu11
GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS = YES
SDKROOT = iphoneos
GCC_WARN_64_TO_32_BIT_CONVERSION = YES
GCC_WARN_ABOUT_RETURN_TYPE = YES_ERROR
GCC_WARN_UNDECLARED_SELECTOR = YES
GCC_WARN_UNINITIALIZED_AUTOS = YES_AGGRESSIVE
GCC_WARN_UNUSED_FUNCTION = YES
GCC_WARN_UNUSED_VARIABLE = YES
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.2

// Custom set
CODE_SIGN_STYLE = Manual
SWIFT_VERSION = 4.1
DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = MYTEAMIDGOESHERE
ENABLE_BITCODE = NO
CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS =
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY =
```

### `base_debug.xcconfig`:

```
_DEBUG = DEBUG
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(_DEBUG)
DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT = dwarf
ENABLE_TESTABILITY = YES
GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC = NO
GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = 0
MTL_ENABLE_DEBUG_INFO = YES
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES
SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS = DEBUG
SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = -Onone
SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS = $(inherited) $(_DEBUG)
```

### `base_release.xcconfig`:

```
DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT = dwarf-with-dsym
ENABLE_NS_ASSERTIONS = NO
MTL_ENABLE_DEBUG_INFO = NO
SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE = wholemodule
SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = -O
VALIDATE_PRODUCT = YES
```

### `base_apps.xcconfig`:

```
#include "base_shared.xcconfig"
// Apps have no specific BuildSettings that the FRAMEWORKS does not have as well. But in the future they might have, thus we have this file.

// These settings were in the TravelCompanion xcconfig
SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS[sdk=iphonesimulator*] = $(inherited) IOS_SIMULATOR
MTL_ENABLE_DEBUG_INFO = NO
SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = -O
DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT = dwarf-with-dsym
ENABLE_NS_ASSERTIONS = NO
VALIDATE_PRODUCT = YES
SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS = iphonesimulator iphoneos
VALID_ARCHS = arm64 armv7 armv7s
CLANG_MODULES_AUTOLINK = YES
GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = s
CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE = NO
TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 1
CLANG_ANALYZER_LOCALIZABILITY_NONLOCALIZED = YES
VERSIONING_SYSTEM = apple_generic

// Custom
// The flag `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` should be set to `YES` for apps and `NO` for frameworks
ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES = YES
```

### `base_framework.xcconfig`:

```
#include "base_shared.xcconfig"

// BuildSettings specific for FRAMEWORKS (Cocoa Touch Framework)

// Vanilla BuildSettings
CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = 1
VERSIONING_SYSTEM = apple-generic
VERSION_INFO_PREFIX =

// Custom Set
PRODUCT_NAME = $(TARGET_NAME:c99extidentifier)
INSTALL_PATH = $(LOCAL_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks
DYLIB_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION = 1
DYLIB_CURRENT_VERSION = 1
DEFINES_MODULE = YES
SKIP_INSTALL = YES


// The flag `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` should be set to `YES` for apps and `NO` for frameworks
ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES = NO

LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks @loader_path/Frameworks
```

### `base_tests.xcconfig`:

```
#include "base_shared.xcconfig"

ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES

//Only used by APPS but it does not mess up build settings for test targets for FRAMEWORKS in Xcode 9.3 so will keep it here for now
BUNDLE_LOADER = $(TEST_HOST)
```

### `base_uitests.xcconfig`:

```
#include "base_shared.xcconfig"
TEST_TARGET_NAME = $(PRODUCT_NAME)
```

### `Models-Common.xcconfig`:

```
#include "../../../../Configurations/base_framework.xcconfig"

INFOPLIST_FILE = Source/SupportingFiles/Models-Info.plist
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.sajjon.Models
```

### `Models-Debug.xcconfig`:

```
#include "Models-Common.xcconfig"
#include "../../../../Configurations/base_debug.xcconfig"
#include "../../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Framework-Models-Models/Pods-Framework-Models-Models.debug.xcconfig"
```

### `Models-Release.xcconfig`:

```
#include "Models-Common.xcconfig"
#include "../../../../Configurations/base_release.xcconfig"
#include "../../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Framework-Models-Models/Pods-Framework-Models-Models.release.xcconfig"
```

### `ModelsTests-Common.xcconfig`:

```
#include "../../../../Configurations/base_framework.xcconfig"
#include "../../../../Configurations/base_tests.xcconfig"
INFOPLIST_FILE = Tests/SupportingFiles/ModelsTests-Info.plist
```

### `ModelsTests-Debug.xcconfig`:

```
#include "ModelsTests-Common.xcconfig"
#include "../../../../Configurations/base_debug.xcconfig"
#include "../../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Framework-Models-ModelsTests/Pods-Framework-Models-ModelsTests.debug.xcconfig"
```

### `ModelsTests-Release.xcconfig`:

```
#include "ModelsTests-Common.xcconfig"
#include "../../../../Configurations/base_release.xcconfig"
#include "../../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Framework-Models-ModelsTests/Pods-Framework-Models-ModelsTests.release.xcconfig"
```

### `MyiPhoneApp-Commong.xcconfig`:

```
#include "../../../../Configurations/base_apps.xcconfig"

_APP_NAME_PROD = My iPhone App
_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER_PROD = com.sajjon.myiphoneaop
INFOPLIST_FILE = Source/SupportingFiles/MyiPhoneApp-Info.plist

DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = MYTEAMGOESHERE

PRODUCT_NAME = $(_APP_NAME_PROD)
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME = LaunchImage

CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = Source/SupportingFiles/$(_APP_NAME_PROD).entitlements
SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = Source/SupportingFiles/MyiPhoneApp-Bridging-Header.h

PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME = TravelCompanion

// Overridden in Debug.xcconfig
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Distribution

// Overridden in Release.xcconfig
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon-Alpha

ENABLE_TESTABILITY = YES
```

### `MyiPhoneApp-Debug.xcconfig`:

```
#include "MyiPhoneApp-Common.xcconfig"
#include "../../../../Configurations/base_debug.xcconfig"
#include "../../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MyiPhoneApp/Pods-MyiPhoneApp.debug.xcconfig"

_DEBUG = DEBUG
_CODE_SIGN_ID_DEBUG = iPhone Developer
_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER_DEBUG = $(_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER_PROD).dev
_PP_DEBUG = match Development $(_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER_DEBUG)

CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = $(_CODE_SIGN_ID_DEBUG)

PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER = $(_PP_DEBUG)
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = $(_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER_DEBUG)
APP_DISPLAY_NAME = MyiPhoneApp
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon-Debug
SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS = $(inherited) $(_DEBUG)
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(_DEBUG)
GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = 0
GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = 0
MTL_ENABLE_DEBUG_INFO = YES
SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = -Onone
GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC = NO
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES
ENABLE_NS_ASSERTIONS = YES
ENABLE_NS_ASSERTIONS[sdk=iphoneos*] = YES
VALIDATE_PRODUCT = NO
```

### `MyiPhoneApp-Release.xcconfig`:

```
#include "MyiPhoneApp-Common.xcconfig"
#include "../../../../Configurations/base_release.xcconfig"
#include "../../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MyiPhoneApp/Pods-MyiPhoneApp.release.xcconfig"

_PP_PROD = match AppStore $(_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER_PROD)

PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER = $(_PP_PROD)
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = $(_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER_PROD)
APP_DISPLAY_NAME = $(_APP_NAME_PROD)
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon-Production
SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS = $(inherited) APP_STORE_BUILD
SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = -Owholemodule
```

Answer (score 1):

We had similar problem in our project where we had lot of custom frameworks. We had two build configurations for each framework which is DEBUG and RELEASE. And We only enabled ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES for DEBUG builds on which we used to run tests.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :) I too thought about that but I felt reluctant since "it is more proper" to test the same binary that we upload, is it not? But for now, I will use this proposed solution. Can anyone come up with another solution allowing us to tests using release config?