# flutter application problem sending an ios build to the store using bitrise

Tags: ios, flutter, bitrise

flutter application

it's a flutter application and I'm using different flavors, dev, stage and prd, however on ios they are treated for the use of scheme and everything is working well when generating a build and on android it also works well

the build is done ok local, but when trying anything to the store the following error and I don’t know how to proceed anymore, I’ve been nissa for a while,
the error in the step deploy-to-itunesconnect-application-loader

below follows the log

```
[2021-01-28 12:58:20 UTC] <main> DBG-X:   parameter StreamingInfoList = [file: ae2a6f95-ffe0-42f5-aef7-3d432be07e37403829916168064513.swinfo.plist.gz, content-length: 92047, content-type: application/binary, MD5: 5b1a0e6289bf43214e13ee3e4160e0b1]
[2021-01-28 12:58:20 UTC] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Transport = HTTP
[2021-01-28 12:58:20 UTC] <main> DBG-X:   parameter TransporterArguments = -m upload -u [REDACTED] -vp json -DTxHeaders=eyJqZW5nYSI6dHJ1ZX0= -sessionid @env:BC6E6689-1239-49AE-B406-3634514D7AE8 -sharedsecret **hidden value** -f /var/folders/6q/wgy6jtp12w5gzgm9lzcglpqw0000gn/T/59B599DB-FF72-403A-B009-101CF19DE202/1545439899.itmsp -indicator true -v eXtreme -Dtransporter.client=altool -Dtransporter.client.version=4.01 (1182)
[2021-01-28 12:58:20 UTC] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Version = 2.1.0
[2021-01-28 12:58:20 UTC] <main> DBG-X:   parameter iTMSTransporterMode = upload
[2021-01-28 12:58:20 UTC] <main>  INFO: id = 20210128125820-728
[2021-01-28 12:58:20 UTC] <main>  INFO: iTMSTransporter Correlation Key: ec837441-acbc-4be1-a606-984bbbc17d09-0001
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> DBG-X: Apple's web service operation return value:
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> DBG-X:   parameter EnableJWTForAllCalls = false
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> DBG-X:   parameter MinimumFileSizeThresholdForCheckum = 104857600
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> DBG-X:   parameter SoftwareMediaDescriptionFormat = binary
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> DBG-X:   parameter RestartClient = false
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> DBG-X:   parameter SoftwareMediaDescriptionThresholds = {in-app-purchase-content={extensions=[pkg], size=100000000}, ccats={extensions=[pdf], size=100000000}, product-archive={extensions=[pkg], size=100000000}, developer-id-package={extensions=[zip, pkg, dmg], size=100000000}, bundle={extensions=[zip, ipa], size=100000000}, large-icon={extensions=[jpg, png, jpeg], size=100000000}}
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Success = false
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Errors = [ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex/Frameworks/Pods_OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.framework/Pods_OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure.", ERROR ITMS-90060: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString '$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)' in the Info.plist file at '${bundlePath}' must be a period-separated list of at most three non-negative integers. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring", ERROR ITMS-90057: "The bundle 'Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' is missing plist key. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring", ERROR ITMS-90056: "This bundle Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex is invalid. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleVersion. Please find more information about CFBundleVersion at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleversion", ERROR ITMS-90205: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' contains disallowed nested bundles.", ERROR ITMS-90206: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'.", ERROR ITMS-90360: "Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'CFBundleVersion' in bundle Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex is required.", ERROR ITMS-90360: "Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'CFBundleShortVersionString' in bundle Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex is required."]
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> DBG-X:   parameter FilesToUpload = [metadata.xml, dev.ipa]
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> DBG-X:   parameter AssetsToDescribe = [{Role=source, Filename=dev.ipa, ShouldDescribeAsset=true, UTI=com.apple.ipa}]
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Checksums = {dev.ipa=b0a15b65518f7e54bedab1a98fa15f71}
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> DBG-X:   parameter FileSizes = {dev.ipa=57857848}
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ErrorCode = 1102
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ErrorMessage = ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex/Frameworks/Pods_OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.framework/Pods_OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."
ERROR ITMS-90060: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString '$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)' in the Info.plist file at '${bundlePath}' must be a period-separated list of at most three non-negative integers. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring"
ERROR ITMS-90057: "The bundle 'Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' is missing plist key. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring"
ERROR ITMS-90056: "This bundle Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex is invalid. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleVersion. Please find more information about CFBundleVersion at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleversion"
ERROR ITMS-90205: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' contains disallowed nested bundles."
ERROR ITMS-90206: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'."
ERROR ITMS-90360: "Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'CFBundleVersion' in bundle Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex is required."
ERROR ITMS-90360: "Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'CFBundleShortVersionString' in bundle Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex is required.
 (1102)
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ShouldUseRESTAPIs = false
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex/Frameworks/Pods_OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.framework/Pods_OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90060: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString '$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)' in the Info.plist file at '${bundlePath}' must be a period-separated list of at most three non-negative integers. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring"
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90057: "The bundle 'Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' is missing plist key. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring"
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90056: "This bundle Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex is invalid. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleVersion. Please find more information about CFBundleVersion at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleversion"
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90205: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' contains disallowed nested bundles."
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90206: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'."
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90360: "Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'CFBundleVersion' in bundle Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex is required."
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90360: "Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'CFBundleShortVersionString' in bundle Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex is required."
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> DBG-X: The error code is: 1102
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main>  INFO: Done performing authentication.
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main>  INFO: JSON:{"msg":{"phase":"Upload","count":3,"description":"Operation failed","index":3},"messageType":"VerifyProgress"}
[2021-01-28 12:58:49 UTC] <main> DBG-X: Returning 1
2021-01-28 12:58:49.797 altool[7800:32494]  Out:
Package Summary:
 
1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:
    /var/folders/6q/wgy6jtp12w5gzgm9lzcglpqw0000gn/T/59B599DB-FF72-403A-B009-101CF19DE202/1545439899.itmsp - Error Messages:
        ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex/Frameworks/Pods_OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.framework/Pods_OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."
        ERROR ITMS-90060: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString '$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)' in the Info.plist file at '${bundlePath}' must be a period-separated list of at most three non-negative integers. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring"
        ERROR ITMS-90057: "The bundle 'Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' is missing plist key. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring"
        ERROR ITMS-90056: "This bundle Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex is invalid. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleVersion. Please find more information about CFBundleVersion at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleversion"
        ERROR ITMS-90205: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' contains disallowed nested bundles."
        ERROR ITMS-90206: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'."
        ERROR ITMS-90360: "Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'CFBundleVersion' in bundle Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex is required."
        ERROR ITMS-90360: "Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'CFBundleShortVersionString' in bundle Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex is required."
2021-01-28 12:58:49.810 altool[7800:32484] *** Error: Error uploading '/Users/vagrant/deploy/dev.ipa'.
2021-01-28 12:58:49.810 altool[7800:32484] *** Error: code -18000 (ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex/Frameworks/Pods_OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.framework/Pods_OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure.")
2021-01-28 12:58:49.810 altool[7800:32484] *** Error: code -18000 (ERROR ITMS-90060: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString '$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)' in the Info.plist file at '${bundlePath}' must be a period-separated list of at most three non-negative integers. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring")
2021-01-28 12:58:49.810 altool[7800:32484] *** Error: code -18000 (ERROR ITMS-90057: "The bundle 'Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' is missing plist key. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring")
2021-01-28 12:58:49.810 altool[7800:32484] *** Error: code -18000 (ERROR ITMS-90056: "This bundle Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex is invalid. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleVersion. Please find more information about CFBundleVersion at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleversion")
2021-01-28 12:58:49.810 altool[7800:32484] *** Error: code -18000 (ERROR ITMS-90205: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' contains disallowed nested bundles.")
2021-01-28 12:58:49.810 altool[7800:32484] *** Error: code -18000 (ERROR ITMS-90206: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'.")
2021-01-28 12:58:49.810 altool[7800:32484] *** Error: code -18000 (ERROR ITMS-90360: "Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'CFBundleVersion' in bundle Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex is required.")
2021-01-28 12:58:49.810 altool[7800:32484] *** Error: code -18000 (ERROR ITMS-90360: "Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'CFBundleShortVersionString' in bundle Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex is required.")
Uploading IPA failed: exit status 1
|                                                                              |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| x | deploy-to-itunesconnect-application-loader@0 (exit code: 1)   | 1.4 min  |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Issue tracker: ...ib/steps-deploy-to-itunesconnect-application-loader/issues |
| Source: .../bitrise-steplib/steps-deploy-to-itunesconnect-application-loader |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
                                          ▼
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

| (10) deploy-to-bitrise-io@1                                                  |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| - | deploy-to-bitrise-io@1                                        | 3.06 sec |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
                                          ▼
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

| (11) cache-push@2                                                            |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| ✓ | cache-push@2                                                  | 27.17 sec|
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
                                          ▼
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

| (12) microsoft-teams-integration@1                                           |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| ✓ | microsoft-teams-integration@1                                 | 7.22 sec |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                               bitrise summary                                |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|   | title                                                         | time (s) |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| ✓ | activate-ssh-key@4                                            | 11.02 sec|
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| ✓ | git-clone@4                                                   | 9.68 sec |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| ✓ | Do anything with Script step                                  | 3.31 sec |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| ✓ | flutter-installer@0                                           | 9.65 sec |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| ✓ | cache-pull@2                                                  | 45.58 sec|
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| ✓ | flutter-build@0                                               | 9.9 min  |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| ✓ | set-xcode-build-number@1                                      | 3.47 sec |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| ✓ | ios-auto-provision-appstoreconnect@0                          | 30.47 sec|
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| ✓ | xcode-archive@3                                               | 5.1 min  |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| x | deploy-to-itunesconnect-application-loader@0 (exit code: 1)   | 1.4 min  |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Issue tracker: ...ib/steps-deploy-to-itunesconnect-application-loader/issues |
| Source: .../bitrise-steplib/steps-deploy-to-itunesconnect-application-loader |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| - | deploy-to-bitrise-io@1                                        | 3.06 sec |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| ✓ | cache-push@2                                                  | 27.17 sec|
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| ✓ | microsoft-teams-integration@1                                 | 7.22 sec |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Total runtime: 18.9 min                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Submitting anonymized usage information...
For more information visit:
https://github.com/bitrise-io/bitrise-plugins-analytics/blob/master/README.md
exit status 1
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to using Swift (both the app and the extension make use of Swift).

For the app

```
Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries: YES
```

and for the extension:

```
Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries: NO
```

To reach this option:

1. Select you project from the **Project Navigator**
2. Select app or extension **target**
3. Select **Build Settings** tab
4. Search for `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES`

Please find the original [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25789145/1599713).