# XCode13, React Native passbase library cannot be uploaded to Appstore

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode13

I'm trying to use @passbase/react-native-passbase 2.12.0 library.
And on android, it has no problem.
But on iOS build, it uses react native microblink 5.15.2 library as dependency, but it is rejected by appstore.

I tried below:

1. On MacOS12.3 Monterey terminal

```
# yarn
// successfully done
# cd ios
# pod install
// successfully done
# npx react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios
// successfully done
```

2. Open Xcode 13.3(13E113)

- Product/Archive
  // build successfully done
- Distribute App
  // When uploading to testflight, it shows this error when build.
  The bundle at '.../Frameworks/Microblink.framework' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'. With error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90206 for id 8cb0ca18-f4be-405d-91e7-6efb0dee6515

So I tried to fix this issue using this method,
[Validation Error: Invalid Bundle. The bundle at ... contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777958/validation-error-invalid-bundle-the-bundle-at-contains-disallowed-file-fr)

3. After apply that method, error not shown, but finally, on testflight, it gives "Invalid Binary" error.
   I have no idea to solve this.

Anyone have solution for this problem? If so, please kindly provide answer.
Thank you.

Comment: I came across the 'Invalid binary' issue before and just changing the build version in xCode resolved it for me.  Not sure if you tried that already? Also, Apple sometimes sends out an email specifying why you have an invalid binary - not sure if it's any different now, usually it was a missing permission request or similar in the .plist file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I appended details.