# Invalid bundle structure - iOS App Submission Issue

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I received the following error after trying to upload my app to AppStore Connect.

```
Asset validation failed (90171)
Invalid bundle structure. The “Runner.app/PlugIns/ImageNotification.appex/Frameworks/Pods_ImageNotification.framework/Pods_ImageNotification” binary file is not permitted. Your app cannot contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/placing_content_in_a_bundle (ID: 9022756e-defb-44d9-ba55-70e01abeab11)

Asset validation failed (90206)
Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'Runner.app/PlugIns/ImageNotification.appex' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'. (ID: b889e1b7-84e5-4cdd-b011-c5ef51a78daa)

Asset validation failed (90205)
Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'Runner.app/PlugIns/ImageNotification.appex' contains disallowed nested bundles. (ID: 6a71e1d9-4c46-4528-aa04-05fcb4bf6fe0)
```

Comment: See these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777958/validation-error-invalid-bundle-the-bundle-at-contains-disallowed-file-fr?lq=1) and [Apple forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/17732)

Comment: i faced the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by deleting podfile.lock and podfile folder + flutter clean.

An error of mutiple produce came up and i added below line to my podfile

```
pod 'GoogleUtilities'
```

And everything works fine afterwards.